# how to not open specific URL in the app deeplink and open it in the browser instead

Tags: flutter, deep-linking

So we integrated deep links in a flutter app, but the problem now is that any link opens the app if its installed, is there a way to not open specific URL in the app  and open it in the browser instead
we want the unsubscribe link to open in the browser like : example.com/unsubscribe

Comment: You can just remove the intent-filter from your manifest.xml file. It will stop detecting the deeplinks.